# Django create file programatically on save

Tags: python, django

The goal with this is for the user to create an instance of the model where they populate a `source` URLField, and on save, it would fetch the URL and save it as a file.

```py
class ComicImage(UUIDModel):
    src = models.URLField('Comic URL', max_length=512, blank=True)
    img = models.FileField('Images', null=True, blank=True, upload_to='comics')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        img_data = BytesIO(requests.get(self.src).content)
        self.img.save(f'{self.hash}-i.webp', content=img_data)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But I keep getting an error

> ValueError: The 'img' attribute has no file associated with it.

Which appears that it's not assigning a file to the field. Or rather, it doesn't until AFTER the model is saved.

**Alternatively:**

I also tried

```py
self.img.save(f'{self.hash}-i.webp', content=img_data, save=True)
```

But it gets stuck in a loop of saving forever.  If I set `save=False`, then it creates the model but not the file.

Is there a way to create/populate/modify the file before it's saved?

Comment: I think the simplest way is to create another image model with `OneToOneField` and create relation inside `save()`

Comment: Who is your user? Is it another programmer writing their own Django app or is it someone that visits a website that is powered by your Django app. I ask to clarify your statement "the user to create an instance of the model"? If "the user" here is someone that loads a web page in a browser, then they don't "create an instance of the model". Rather, the browser makes a request to an endpoint which is implemented by a view in your Django app.

Comment: Have you checked what `requests.get().content` is? What about `img_data`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it's being used internally as an api.  I meant an endpoint that creates an instance of the model.  @sudden_appearance This is already an extra model for the img as I couldn't store files in an `ArrayField`.  I'd rather not add another model on top of that.

Comment: @cclloyd did you see my second comment?